# App Xcode 8 to Xcode 9 - Prevent Auto Hide Status Bar

Tags: ios, statusbar, xcode9

When I open and close the control center, the status bar disappears automatically.

I do not want this behavior and it happens since I migrated the project from xcode 8 to 9. Occurs in iOS11 and iOS10.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
In the info.plist i have to change

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = No
```

To

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is coincidence (about version of XCode).
Check that you override [`prefersStatusBarHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden) in your viewController:

```
 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
 {
    return NO;
 }
```

Also you can call [`setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621354-setneedsstatusbarappearanceupdat?language=objc) when your application receives [`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdidbecomeactivenotification?language=objc)